# Javascript replace occurence of ID from string

Tags: javascript

In Javascript I am trying to:

remove ID of 5dc422e9 from lib-One-5dc422e9,

remove ID of 5dc422e9gfg from lib-Six-5dc422e9gfg and so on.

I want to retain everything in JSON string, just want to remove the ID part at end of `lib-*-`

```
{
   "data":{
      "Library":{
         "Checkout":{
            "invoiceId":"12dfdf454546",
            "checkoutDetail":{
               "invoiceTransactionId":"5ab422e9",
               "invoicePaymentDetail":{
                  "bookId":"lib-One-5dc422e9",
                  "checkoutPeriods":[
                     {
                        "startDate":"2017-04-14T19:00:00.000",
                        "endDate":"2017-05-19T19:00:00.000"
                     }
                  ],
                  "invoice":{
                     "bookId":"lib-Six-5dc422e9gfg",
                     "checkObject":true
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [String#replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with some regex.

> The replace() method returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement. The pattern can be a string or a RegExp, and the replacement can be a string or a function to be called for each match. If pattern is a string, only the first occurrence will be replaced.

*second parameter of the replace method I used a callback function*

### regex

i.e.: `/(lib-[^-]+-)[^"]+/g`

### explanation

`[^-]`+ find anything that isn't `-`

`(lib-[^-]+-)` match anything like `lib-*-`

`[^"]+` find anything that isn't `"` (the id)

### solution

```js
const data = {"data":{"Library":{"Checkout":{"invoiceId":"12dfdf454546","checkoutDetail":{"invoiceTransactionId":"5ab422e9","invoicePaymentDetail":{"bookId":"lib-One-5dc422e9","checkoutPeriods":[{"startDate":"2017-04-14T19:00:00.000","endDate":"2017-05-19T19:00:00.000"}],"invoice":{"bookId":"lib-Six-5dc422e9gfg","checkObject":true}}}}}}};

const res = JSON.stringify(data).replace(/(lib-[^-]+-)[^"]+/g, (_, match)=>match);

console.log(JSON.parse(res, null, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the ID is always like this "lib-[word]-", you can do something like this:

```
"lib-Six-5dc422e9gfg".split("-")[2]
```